# AVPlayer subview resize when device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, avplayer

I am having a problem when the iPad is rotated the sub views frame needs to be changed to landscape as well.

The video is used as a landing screen on the home page and is played behind various elements on the page.

The problem is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3PWI.jpg)

I currently have the code that detects if the screen is in landscape or horizontal which will be used to make the changes to the sub view if possible.

The player is set up using the code shown:

```
    player = AVPlayer(URL: contentURL!)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player.muted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.play()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @onemillion, Your problem is same with me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132122/avplayer-rotate-view-makes-cannot-tap-to-the-screen . Did you get a solution?