# AVPlayer Rotate View makes cannot tap to the screen

Tags: swift3, media-player, avplayer, avaudioplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I used **AVPlayer** for movie player in my app. I explained the problem with diagrams.

[image]

When I click Play button in movie view controller(Portrait mode),then goes to movie details view. When I tap on the screen , the navigation bar and movie player bar appear. If you tap again the screen, it will disappear. This goes well when the device is in Portrait mode.

But, I changed my code to Landscape mode when I click on play button, it will automatically change to Landscape mode in movie details view.

So, the problem in here is that when I do like that, tapped area is only in top and cannot tap any other places. 
**This happens when previous view controller(Movie View Controller) is in *Portrait* mode and Movie Details View is in *Landscape* mode.**

[image]

The problem won't happen if **first** view controller(Movie View Controller) is in **Landscape** mode and **second** view controller (Movie Details view controller) is in **Landscape** mode.

I have no idea of how do I solve this problem. Does first view controller rotation mode effects to second view controller? 
Please anyone help me this? 
 Thanks for reading my long paragraph.